# Datatable sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a web form that allows users to add data and view the data that they have just entered in the gridview control on the page. The problem that I am having is that the focus of the page stays on the text box on the top of the page and the most recent data that was captured was added to the bottom of the grid.Due to the volume of data that is being captured it no longer appears on the page. I am using a datatable to populate the gridview control. Is there anyway to sort this so that the newly added items are add to the top of the gridview rather than the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Sort` property of `DefaultView` of your `Datatable`

```
DataView dv = datatable.DefaultView;   
dv.Sort = "ColumnID desc"; 
GridView1.DataSource = dv;
GridView1.DataBind();
```